# SSIS split output to multiple files based on field content

Tags: ssis-2012

I have an excel spreadsheet with a column containing school names and other data - over 30 schools. I want to do the equivalent of filtering out all schools of 1 name into its own spreadsheet so I end up with over 30 separate files. Is this possible to do in SSIS only?

I expect to end up with as many spreadsheet as there are distinct schools in the chosen column.

I have managed to do it where I actually name an individual school ie `[school]=="John Smeaton"` but I cannot name all schools and will have to keep updating the script when new schools emerge or close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes will do so using SSIS package.
I am explaining it with the help of similar example:
[image]
In my case the source file is also a CSV file.
Here I am trying to create a separate csv file for each Employee.

**Steps to create separate csv file for each employee.**

step 1.Create a data flow task which extract the records from CSV file  and store them into a recordset Destination.

[image]
 [image]

step 2.Create a Foreach Container and configure the recordset(we create above) with foreach container and iterate accordingly.

[image]

Step 3.Create a User defined variable and store the employee number into it at every iteration.
[image]

[image]

Step 4:Now create a data flow task inside the foreach container which reads the employee number from user defined variable and extract the employee details from the Source CSV file and  and save the details into CSV file.

[image]

Here is conditional split Settings
[image]
Here is flat file Destination settings.
[image]

Final package :
[image]

Step 5: Execute the container[image]

Output After executing the package:

[image]

Comment: Good answer. Maybe show him the settings of your conditional split and your flat file source in your last loop :)

Comment: Added the setting of conditional split and flat file source into the blog.